# Load An Xml File to OLEDB Destination using BIML -SSIS

Tags: ssis-2012, biml

I am trying to load an XML File to a database table, XML has the nodes as (EmpID, Name, Address1 and Address2) , I wanted to load this into Two tables Employee(EmpID,Name) and EmployeeAddress(EmplD,Address1,Address2)

Problem I'm Facing: When i'm trying to Input Path for OLEDB destination its throwing Error in    ,Im using the below code, Can you please help on identifying the issue
I'm using the below code to load the file

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
```

```
  <Tasks >
   <Dataflow Name="DataflowTask1">
      <Transformations>
        <XmlSource Name="XMLSource1">
          <XmlSchemaFileInput ConnectionName="XmlXsd" />
          <FileInput ConnectionName="XmlFile" />
        </XmlSource>

        <OleDbDestination Name="OLe DB Des" ConnectionName="Destination" >
         ** <InputPath OutputPathName="XMLSource1.Output">  </InputPath>**
          <ExternalTableOutput Table="[Employee]" >

          </ExternalTableOutput>
          <Columns>
            <Column SourceColumn="empid" TargetColumn="EmpID"  />
            <Column SourceColumn="name" TargetColumn="Empname"  />

          </Columns>
        </OleDbDestination>
      </Transformations>
    </Dataflow>
   </Tasks>
</Package>
```

Comment: What is the error that it is throwing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your xml file contains `xmlns="..."` and you need to add 
`with xmlnamespaces('...' as x, '....' as y) select ...`

Look at better description at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx